# Write list of dicts to csv with values in separate columns

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm having a hard time understanding how to write a list of dicts to csv in which all of my values are in separate columns. Questions similar to this here on SO have not helped me understand. I've been using the DictWriter but can't figure out how to feed the dict.values() in without an error 'field x not in fieldnames'.

.....

```
dicts = [
  {'sku': 'xxxx1', 'model': '1234-56K', 'price': '$xxx.xx', 'name': 'item_name_here', 'stock': 'True'},
  {'sku': 'xxxx2', 'model': '1234-56K', 'price': '$xxx.xx', 'name': 'item_name_here', 'stock': 'False'}
]

csv_file = open('file.csv','wb')
fieldnames = ('name', 'price', 'stock', 'model', 'sku')
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames, extrasaction='raise', dialect='excel')
csvwriter.writeheader()
csvwriter.writerows(dicts)
return csv_file
```

.....

This returns my values in a single column, but when I iterate over the values of the dicts in the list it simply splits all values (as string) into 's,t,r,i,n,g,' still placing them into the first column.

Comment: that worked for me... is there more code that you did not include?

Comment: Are you using python3 or python2?  I just tried your code in python2.7 and it appeared to work just fine.

Comment: Note that the way columns appear in an excel-like program is distinct from how the csv file gets written. I had very annoying problems using LibreOffice's Calc to display a csv file I wrote with Python, but the problem was the separator that the program was using to break up the data into columns.

Comment: I see you having multiple problems here. If you are getting an error related to a field not included in fieldnames, then that seems to indicate your data is not clean. If you have strings getting split up, then that seems to indicate possibly formatting or inputting your data incorrectly. Finally, the issue of getting data into separate columns, which you named your question after, might have yet another cause.

Comment: Bepetersn - You were right - it was totally my use of LibreOffice - the file wrote just fine and opens in Excel without any formatting issues.  Thanks to all for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for [csv.DictWriter()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

> If the dictionary passed to the writerow() method contains a key not found in fieldnames, the optional extrasaction parameter indicates what action to take. If it is set to 'raise' a ValueError is raised. If it is set to 'ignore', extra values in the dictionary are ignored.

If this is the error you are getting, try:
`csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore', dialect='excel')`

Comment: Having `extrasaction='raise'` would certainly make it possible to get an `'field x not in fieldnames'` error if one of the dicts in the list has an unknown fieldname.

Comment: The dicts in question are custom dicts from a scraping project. There aren't any additional keys I didn't account for, but potentially some missing values, so I thought I should use this. Unfortunately, I didn't see any change removing it either!

Comment: I assumed you were getting the ValueError.  Maybe post the traceback?

Comment: Did you remove the argument or set it to ```'ignore'```? - It defaults to ```'raise'```.

Answer (score 0):

hey i wrote this for Python 2.7

This function takes a list of dictionaries and outputs a csv.  It also include options to set the order of the field in fieldNames, defaultFieldValues, sortField, and option to remove duplicates

https://gist.github.com/brendancol/6816393

```
def write_csv(outputRowDictionaries, outputFile, fieldNames=None, defaultFieldValue='', removeDuplicates=False, sortField=None):
....
```